# How to get if enum value is > const N inside switch statement for C++ enum?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

having:

```
switch(val){
    case 1:
    break;
    case 2:
    break;
}
```

Is it possible to add to it `case val > N:` for `const long long N = 100;`?

Comment: add a `default` and make a series of fallthrough cases from N to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could suggest this:

```
switch(val){
    case 1:
    break;
    case 2:
    break;
    case 3:
    case 4: //etc
    default:
     //case > 100
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that he needlessly creates a host of empty case statements to screen out the values he doesn't want? That's an excessively clumsy, verbose, error prone and pesimal solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not as part of the switch, do this:

```
if ( val > N)
{
   // whatever
} else {
  switch(val){
    case 1:
    break;
    case 2:
    break;
  }
}
```

`case`'s can only be single constant values. The reason it is like this is because the `switch` statement of C was supposed to be implementable as a jump table. Higher level languages frequently allow more complex comparisons making it effectively syntactic sugar for a series of `if () {} else if () {}` statements.

Comment: "Other languages", not "Higher level languages". `<g>`

Comment: I can't think of a lower level language that implements it that way, can you?

Answer (score 1):

No, C++ `switch` cases only handles single values.

You could add a `default` case with an `if` statement to check for a range. Or just use `if` directly without `switch`.